# How to prove that $(R; S;R)^n \subseteq (R; S)^n;R$ for all $n \geqslant 1$.

Tags: relations

If $R; S$ be relations on a set $U$. Given $R$ is transitive.

How to prove that $(R; S;R)^n \subseteq (R; S)^n;R$
for all $n \geqslant 1$.

Comment: What does $(R;S;R)$ mean?

Comment: ; means composition here

Comment: Ok, I've got a proof. Before I write it down, though: which "direction" have you defined composition of relations? Does $(x,y)\in R;S$ mean that there is a $z$ such that $xRz$ and $zSy$ (the intuitive way), or such that $zRy$ and $xSz$ (which fits the notation for function composition)?

Comment: I guess the 1st one is what I require.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We want to show that
$$
\overbrace{R;S;R;R;S;R;\cdots;R;R;S;R}^{S\text{ appears }n\text{ times}}\subseteq \overbrace{R;S;R;S;R;\cdots;S;R;S;R}^{S\text{ appears }n\text{ times}}
$$
The normal way of doing that is to take an element of the left-hand set and show that it is an element of the right-hand set. So that is what we will do.

Assume $(x, y) \in (S;R;S)^n$. That means that there are $x_i, y_i, z_i$, with $1\leq i \leq n$ such that
$$
xRx_1, \quad x_1Sy_1, \quad y_1Rz_1\\
z_1Rx_2, \quad x_2Sy_2, \quad y_2Rz_2\\
\vdots\\
z_{n-1}Rx_n, \quad x_nSy_n, \quad y_nRy
$$
Now, every time we see $y_iRz_i$ and $z_iRx_{i+1}$ after one another, we can shorten that (since $R$ is transitive) into just $y_iRx_{i+1}$. That means we have the following chain of related elements:
$$
xRx_1, \quad x_1Sy_1\\
y_1Rx_2, \quad x_2Sy_2\\
\vdots\\
y_{n-1}Rx_n, \quad x_nSy_n\\
\quad y_nRy
$$
which you will recognize as confirmation that $(x, y) \in (R;S)^n;R$. We have therefore shown that any element in $(R;S;R)^n$ is also an element of $(R;S)^n;R$, which is to say that $(R;S;R)^n\subseteq (R;S)^n;R$.